# Typescript - Object is possibly undefined - proper way to "fix" type definition

Tags: typescript

I am using aws dynamodb with this call:

```
const params: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
  TableName: tableName,
  KeyConditionExpression: '#hashKey = :hashValue AND #rangeKey = :rangeValue',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#hashKey': hashKey,
    '#rangeKey': rangeKey
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':hashValue': hashValue,
    ':rangeValue': rangeValue
  },
  IndexName: indexName,
  Limit: fetchLimit,
  ScanIndexForward: true,
  ProjectionExpression: projectionItems.concat([documentKey])
}
// These 2 ridiculous lines are necessary to get rid of error
if (!params.ExpressionAttributeNames) params.ExpressionAttributeNames = {}
if (!params.ExpressionAttributeValues) params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {}

if (beforeDateCondition) {
  params.FilterExpression = '#updatedAt < :updatedAt'
  params.ExpressionAttributeNames['#updatedAt'] = 'updatedAt'. // ERROR HERE
  params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':updatedAt'] = beforeDateCondition // ERROR HERE
}
```

If I dont check and define `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` right after I actually defined them TS gives me errors in the last two lines about it being possibly undefined.

I get that `ExpressionAttributeValues` and `ExpressionAttributeNames` are not required (type is `ExpressionAttributeNames?: ExpressionAttributeNameMap;`) but how can I fix this without:

1. writing lines of code that make me cringe
2. rewriting my own `DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput` definition

What is the proper approach here?